# Does anyone recognise this font?

Tags: font-identification

I'm sorry for the bad quality images, it's all I have. Also it is displayed on a graphical lcd display, running a program called "PowerLCD" made by "Mr.Chronom" but his website seems to be dead, so I can't find anything about this.

http://i.imgup.hu/ltW3J7.png
http://i.imgup.hu/m98HPh.png
http://i.imgup.hu/D3Eki2.png
http://i.imgup.hu/o9A8Rk.png
http://i.imgup.hu/8tkSL2.png
http://i.imgup.hu/hF7xN4.png

Can you help me? These are the only images I have of this font, if you know the name, please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Aka-AcidGR-4B20

---

**Family:** Aka Acid.

**Type:** Pixel Font.

**Designer:** Myrto Orfanoudaki Simic.

**Distribution Type:** Free.

**Copyright:** Cybertronical Design, All rights reserved.

[**Download Link**](http://www.aka-acid.com/fonts/AC4B20.zip)

---

### Sample:

[image]

Comment: unbelievable! You are awesome! Thank you so very much!